# Cannot load Main.axml layout Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I tried the older versions of Android SDK but every time when I try to open Main.axml I get this error:

> System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException:
>   No exports were found that match the constraint: 
>     ContractName    VisualStudioWorkspace
>     RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore(Type
>   type, Type metadataViewType, String contractName, ImportCardinality
>   cardinality)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueCore[T](String
>   contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)    at
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerInterface.GetCodeModelBridge()
>   in
>   C:\data\lanes\3513\00fa5cc4\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerInterface.cs:line
>   154    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.get_CodeModelBridge()    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.d__175.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.d__139.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidRenderSession.d__105.MoveNext()

Comment: Try clearing %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache. What is the version info from Visual Studio > Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio > Copy Info [button]?

Comment: Thanks for the help, problem solved by reinstalling Visual Studio and Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

First update all the Xamarin Forms ( not Xamarin.Android ) nugets.
Then delete bin/obj directories from PCL and Android
Setup Droid MIN sdk to 4.4 KitKat
Make sure project name and version are set in droid.
Build only PCL via right-mouse build.
Build only Droid via right-mouse build.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, problem solved by reinstalling Visual Studio and Xamarin.